# Extract K-th Line from Chunks Using Sed/AWK/Perl

Tags: linux, perl, bash, sed, awk

I have some data that looks like this. It comes in chunk of four lines. Each chunk starts with a `@` character.

```
@SRR037212.1 FC30L5TAA_102708:7:1:741:1355 length=27
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
+SRR037212.1 FC30L5TAA_102708:7:1:741:1355 length=27
::::::::::::::::::::::::;;8
@SRR037212.2 FC30L5TAA_102708:7:1:1045:1765 length=27
TATAACCAGAAAGTTACAAGTAAACAC
+SRR037212.2 FC30L5TAA_102708:7:1:1045:1765 length=27
88888888888888888888888888
```

What I want to do is to extract last line of each chunk. Yielding:

```
::::::::::::::::::::::::;;8
888888888888888888888888888
```

Note that the last line of the chunk may contain any standard ASCII character
including `@`.

Is there an effective one-liner to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following sed command will print the 3rd line after the pattern:

```
sed -n '/^@/{n;n;n;p}' file.txt
```

Answer (score 4):

If there are no blank lines:

```
perl -ne 'print if $. % 4 == 0' file
```

Comment: That’s a lot nicer to look at than `$. % 4 || print`. ☺

Comment: But your solution is cleverer.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{RS="@";FS="\n"}{print $4 } ' file

::::::::::::::::::::::::;;8
88888888888888888888888888
```

If you always have those 4 lines in a chunk, some other ways

```
$ ruby -ne 'print if $.%4==0' file
::::::::::::::::::::::::;;8
88888888888888888888888888

$ awk 'NR%4==0' file
::::::::::::::::::::::::;;8
88888888888888888888888888
```

It also seems like your line is always after the line that start with "+", so

```
$ awk '/^\+/{getline;print}' file
::::::::::::::::::::::::;;8
88888888888888888888888888

$ ruby -ne 'gets && print if /^\+/' file
::::::::::::::::::::::::;;8
88888888888888888888888888
```

Comment: The first awk snippet will not work when there are `@` characters in last line (specifically mentioned by OP)

Answer (score 1):

This prints the lines *before* lines that starts with `@`, and also the last line. It can work with non uniform sized chunks, but assumes that only a chunk leading line starts with `@`.

```
sed -ne '1d;$p;/^@/!{x;d};/^@/{x;p}' file
```

Some explanation is in order:

- First you don't need the first line so delete it `1d`
- Next you always need the last line, so print it `$p`
- If you don't have a match swap it into the hold buffer and delete it `x;d`
- If you do have match swap it out of the hold buffer, and print it `x;p`

Answer (score 1):

This works similarly to dogbane's answer

```
awk '/^@/ {mark = NR} NR == mark + 3 {print}' inputfile
```

And, like that answer, will work regardless of the number of lines in each chunk (as long as there are at least 4).

The direct analog to that answer, however, would be:

```
awk '/^@/ {next; next; next; print}' inputfile
```

Answer (score 0):

this can be done using grep easily

```
grep -A 1 '^@' ./infile
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/^@/,+2d' file
```